# alternatives to $( ".selector" ).tabs( "refresh" ); in jquery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am trying to add and remove tabs dynamically pretty much like this
[jquery dynamic tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) except that i was 
 using jquery 1.5.2 . But the tab panels(div tags) are being added one after the other.i figured out that the problem is with the refresh call which was added in the newer versions of jquery. i tried using tabify after i read [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/8b89febbbb4d2f13c67bc8ec406b68ff29da3a5a#diff-5ae536d539fcc724362960b3ada853edR129) and [this](http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/). but i got an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabify'
```

So is there any alternative to this?

Comment: tabify is not defined.. make sure you load tabify.js ..

Comment: i found an alternative to the entire process. jquery supports $(selector).tabs('add',tabcontent,tablabel) which is deprecated in the latest versions. i am trying to use it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

```
 Be ABSOLUTELY sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file.

    Be sure that you've included the script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
```

Other than that, I checked out the API and you're definitely doing everything right as far as I can see. Best of luck friend!

EDIT: Ensure you close your script tag. There's an answer below that points to that being the solution.

The order of priority must be the following:

```
jQuery.js
Everything that depends on jQuery.
```

It looks like you got that wrong (looking at your code in the question). Change it to this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```